# Getting the Data of SQFLITE Database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sqflite

I am trying to get Data out of a SQFliteDatabase and print it into the Console (and later show as Inkwell Text)
I am trying to get the data like this:

```
var data = select();
onTap: () async => print(await data),
```

This is my select function:

```
Future<List> select() async {
  var db = await getDB();
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('Links');

  return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
    return Titles(
    id: maps[i]['id'],
    title: maps[i]['title'],
    parentTitle: maps[i]['parentTitle'],
    text: maps[i]['text'],
    );
  });
}
```

And this is the result getting printed:

```
I/flutter (27896): [Instance of 'Titles', Instance of 'Titles', Instance of 'Titles', Instance of 'Titles']
```

Can someone help me getting the Raw data and not only the 'instance of' message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
List<Titles> data = await select();
onTap: () async => data.forEach((e) => print(e.toString()));,
```

`await` should be in the front of `select()`

I think your problem can be caused by printing the list instead of a single `Titles` object. Sometimes I've met similar problems and it helped me (of what I remember). Pls comment if it helped you.

Comment: Thank you for the Answer! With the forEach, the print worked fine!

Answer (score 0):

add `await` in front of select method.

```
 var data = await select();
    onTap: () {
        for(var i in data){
          print(i['id']);
       }
    }
```